# Iterate through uiCollectionView to get cell content, strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to retrieve an accessibilityIdentifier from each cell in my UICollectionView.

I create the collectionView doing the following :
-in the cellForItemAtIndexPath function, I create a custom cell with dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

```
- (MyCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"MyCell";        
MyCollectionViewCell *cell;
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then I put an ImageView in my cell and give it an identifier :

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: name];
[imageView.image setAccessibilityIdentifier:name];
cell.imageView = currentImageView;
```

When I try to access this existing collectionView, I meet some serious trouble :

```
NSArray *tableauDesCellules = [self.collectionView visibleCells];
```

returns an array of 0 objects. And when I try to iterate through all visible cells, I get disordered indexes !

```
for(MyCollectionViewCell *cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells)
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.item);
}
```

returns

```
2014-06-30 14:06:16.702 [5685:60b] 38
2014-06-30 14:06:16.702 [5685:60b] 17
2014-06-30 14:06:16.702 [5685:60b] 21
2014-06-30 14:06:16.703 [5685:60b] 0
2014-06-30 14:06:16.703 [5685:60b] 25
2014-06-30 14:06:16.703 [5685:60b] 4
2014-06-30 14:06:16.704 [5685:60b] 29
2014-06-30 14:06:16.704 [5685:60b] 8
2014-06-30 14:06:16.704 [5685:60b] 33
```

As a consequence, my accessibilityIdentifiers are not those which I expected.
I am stuck with it for days and have no idea how to handle it ; any help woud be highly appreciated !

PS : my apologies if my message is not clear enough, English is not my first language, and I am also quite new to iOS development.

Comment: Are you using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or something custom?

Comment: Not a UICollectionViewFlowLayout, but I implement a class derivating from UICollectionViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>,
I also have a custom cell. Is it something that can add some troubles ?

Comment: Since you are using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` it seems you are indeed using flow layout. On your question now: it seems that `visibleCells` does not necessarily return the cells in the order you expect. This has been reported as a bug in open radar (check http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2855401). I don't fully understand the problem that it causes for your app though. Can't you get the accessibility identifiers from the cells themselves? Why do you need the indexpath?

Comment: Thank you very much ! I wasn’t aware of that bug !
You made me realize that I didn’t need to iterate through the collectionVew in the right order, that was just the only logical solution I found. But now I have a temporary solution, in which I just increment counters during the loop. Then I know either these elements are present or not.

Comment: I am not able to access the cells directly because it calls cellForItemAtIndexPath, in which I initialize the cells.
`for(MyCollectionViewCell *cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells)
{
 nom_image = [[cell getImageView].image accessibilityIdentifier];
if([nom_image isEqual:@"beige"])
 beige++;
}
 NSLog(@« Number of :");
 NSLog(@"beige : %d",beige);`
Soory but don't know how to format it properly.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's what you want to do, right? To know what kind of images (as described by their accessibility identifiers) are onscreen. Why do you believe that it's a temporary solution? You need it to be faster? More elegant?

Comment: Well, I think that it's strange to iterate in the disorder, don't you think so ? I was thinking about another solution, with tags (and so I would just have to iterate through these tags). I'd thought it would be a more elegant solution. But I'm not sure…